# SQL field as sum of other fields

Tags: sql, field, sum

This is not query related, what I would like to know is if it's possible to have a field in a column being displayed as a sum of other fields. A bit like Excel does.

As an example, I have two tables:

Recipes

```
nrecepie integer
name varchar(255)
time integer
```

and the other

Instructions

```
nintrucion integer
nrecepie integer
time integer
```

So, basically as a recipe has n instructions I would like that

```
recipes.time = sum(intructions.time)
```

Is this possible to be done in create table script?? if so, how?

Comment: I don't think such a thing is possible as part of `CREATE TABLE` statement. Triggers are used for this kind of functionality OR you can write a stored procedure to do the update (when instructions are added/removed).

Comment: What kind of environment are we talking about?  SQL Server?  Access?  MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW recipes_with_time AS
SELECT nrecepie, name, SUM(Instructions.time) AS total_time
FROM Recepies
JOIN Instructions USING (nrecepie)
GROUP BY Recepies.nrecepie
```

If you really want to have that data in the real table, you must use a trigger.

Comment: Honestly @Martin, this is your best route since you know that the values will always be up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I actually need to do it without view. I'll have to go with triggers

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with an `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` trigger. Every time data is changed in table `Instructions`, the trigger would run and update the time `value` in `Recepies`.

Comment: Thanks, Ill go with triggers. Didn't knew they existed. Ill google them and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to update the time column everytime the instructions table is changed, but a more "normal" (less redundant) way would be to compute the time column via a group by clause on a join between the instructions and recepies [sic] table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends pn the database vendor... In SQL Server for example, you can create a column that calculates it's value based on the values of other columns *in the same row*.   they are called calculated columns, and you do it like this:

```
Create Table MyTable
 (
     colA Integer,
     colB Integer,
     colC Intgeer,
     SumABC As colA + colB + colC
 )
```

In general just put the column name you want, the word 'as' and the formula or equation to ghenerate the value.  This approach uses no aditonal storage, it calculates thevalue each time someone executes a select aganist it, so the table profile remains narrower, and you get better performance.   The only downsode is you cannot put an index on a calculated column.  (although there is a flag in SQL server that allows you to specify to the database that it should persist the value whenever it is created or updated... In which case it can be indexed)

In your example, however, you are accessing data from multiple rows in another table.  To do this, you need a trigger as suggested by other respondants.

Comment: In this case, the OP wants a vertical sum from multiple related records in a separate table (as in an order amount / order total situation)

Comment: Calculated columns cannot access data from another row or table.

Comment: Thanks, answered the question without reading the details of the example.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to avoid situations like that because you're storing derived information (there are exceptions for performance reasons).  Therefore, the best solution is to create a view as suggested by AndreKR.  This provides an always-correct total that is as easy to SELECT from the database as if it were in an actual, stored column.