# update_all with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Lets say I have a model:

```ruby
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :x, :y, :sum
end
```

Instead of doing

```ruby
Result.all.find_each do |s|
  s.sum = compute_sum(s.x, s.y)
  s.save
end
```

assuming `compute_sum` is a available method and does some computation that cannot be translated into SQL.

```ruby
def compute_sum(x,y)
  sum_table[x][y]
end
```

Is there a way to use `update_all`, probably something like:

```ruby
Result.all.update_all(sum: compute_sum(:x, :y))
```

I have more than 80,000 records to update. Each record in `find_each` creates its own `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries, and each record is updated individually.

Or is there any other faster way to do this?

Comment: I have scope and `where(...)` clauses in place of `all`.

Comment: If your sum(s.x, s.y) method is in ruby, you have no option but to do what you are doing here. What you actuall want is to have a code executed by the database. You should try writing a sql script for that. A few ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278582/sql-field-as-sum-of-other-fields .

Comment: Which DMBS are you using?  ie postgres, mysql etc?

Comment: @muichkine I cannot use a SQL function. It will be a part of migration, so it would be executed one-off but the number of records is huge and during the migration the DB would be saturated.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Currently using MariaDB, hoping to migrate to Postgres

Comment: Also, would there be a way to store all the `UPDATE` statements and apply them in bulk, instead of each wrapped in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

Comment: You can `disable_ddl_transaction!` and arrange transaction in a custom way

Comment: @lx00st It might work. Can I wrap the entire `find_each` in a transaction?

Comment: Is your question about making your 80,000 update query more efficient, or how to get the sum method working?

Comment: @RichPeck Either.. whichever is more efficient... There IS going to be a function what takes two values (from columns) as inputs and the output needs to be stored in a column.. `sum` was just an example...

Comment: @ShantanuThatte you're probably starting to realise that it's easier to ask questions with your actual code rather than trying to translate it into an example which ends up causing lots of confusion.

Comment: @Shantau, Yes you can. In this way the whole 80000 rows will be updated in one transaction

Comment: @MaxWilliams I wish, I could.. Its long, deals with 7 different attributes as inputs, computes 3 outputs, and uses more classes and Modules.. 
Basically, the `compute_sum` needs to be treated like a black box...

Comment: Ok, you've just **totally changed** your question, which is really annoying and bad SO protocol.  Given this: **"assuming compute_sum is a available method and does some computation that cannot be translated into SQL."** then it is not possible to use `update_all`, since that simply runs an sql query.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry.... :(

Was trying to simplify the problem... StackOverflow is soo good that I rarely have to ask anything..

Comment: Your attempt to "simplify" it was to say "I want to do this <easy to do in sql> thing in sql".  Then when you get an answer, you say "Oh, but actually i meant "I want to do this <impossible to do in sql> thing in sql".  That's really annoying.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Apologies for the annoyance... And thanks for the advice... Also thanks for sharing the fact that `update_all` can take valid SQL operations... Thats helpful... I'm currently looking into if I can replicate the `compute_sum` logic in SQL...

Really appreciate your help.... Thanks.... and sorry wont do it again...

Comment: BTW what is an initial reason to speed up this migration? Is this timeout error or you just dont want to wait until it ends?

Comment: @MaxWilliams @lx00st Thanks a lot guys for the suggestions. I followed Max's approach to group the data and lx00st's to wrap all in one transaction. I brought the time down from ~25mins to under 30secs. ~80,000 records are split 2 ways, and each set uses two `group_by` blocks.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compute_sum function can't be translated into sql, then you cannot do update_all on all records at once.  You will need to iterate over the individual instances.  However, you could speed it up if there are a lot of repeated sets of values in the columns, by only doing the calculation once per set of inputs, and then doing one mass-update per calculation.  eg

```
Result.all.group_by{|result| [result.x, result.y]}.each do |inputs, results|
  sum = compute_sum(*inputs)
  Result.update_all('sum = #{sum}', "id in (#{results.map(&:id).join(',')})")
end
```

You can replace result.x, result.y with the actual inputs to the compute_sum function.

EDIT - forgot to put the square brackets around result.x, result.y in the group_by block.

Comment: Thanks!!! That would speed it up.. Mixed with @lx00st suggestion to wrap the entire thing in a [ActiveRecord::Base.transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) can speed it up... I'm testing this out.

Answer (score 3):

`update_all` makes an sql query, so any processing you do on the values needs to be in sql.  So, you'll need to find the sql function, in whichever DBMS you're using, to add two numbers together.   In Postgres, for example, i believe you would do

```
Sum.update_all(sum: "x + y")
```

which will generate this sql:

```
update sums set sum = x + y;
```

which will calculate the x + y value for each row, and set the sum field to the result.

EDIT - for MariaDB.  I've never used this, but a quick google suggests that the sql would be

```
update sums set sum = sum(x + y);
```

Try this first, in your sql console, for a single record.  If it works, then you can do

```
Sum.update_all(sum: "sum(x + y)")
```

in Rails.

EDIT2:  there's a lot of things called `sum` here which is making the example quite confusing.  Here's a more generic example.

*set col_c to the result of adding col_a and col_b together, in class Foo:*

```
 Foo.update_all(col_c: "sum(col_a + col_b)")
```

I just noticed that i'd copied the (incorrect) `Sum.all.update_all` from your question.  It should just be `Sum.update_all` - i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. IRL the sum function is a 2-D lookup table (Array, not stored in DB atm). Essentially, something like:
`def sum(x, y)
        sum_table[x][y]
    end`

Comment: I'm confused.  Is there a `sum` column in the `sums` table in your database?  If there isn't, then trying to set it with `update_all` is never going to work.

Comment: Yes there is a `sum` column. What I wanted to illustrate is I want to compute `col_C` with `col_A` and `col_B` as inputs... `sum` was just an example.

Comment: Ok, well my example should work then, where col_C is equivalent to the `sum` column, and col_A and col_B are equivalent to x & y.  It's confusing, unfortunately, that the class in your example is called `Sum`, and the column is called `sum`, and the db function is also called `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely beginner, just wondering Why not add a self block like below, without adding separate column in db, you still can access  Sum.sum from outside.

```
def self.sum 
x+y 
end
```

Comment: The example above was just an illustration. What I wanted to illustrate is I want to compute `col_C` with `col_A` and `col_B` as inputs.

And yes, the data does need to go in the table.

Comment: It's answer for the question, you can achieve the same result in many ways.