# How to use update_all but each? Is there a better method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, psql, seed

Im current working on a small project and I want to seed my database faster. I migrated a new column called "grand_total_points" to my table of users. So originally I was using this code.

```
user = User.all
user.each do |x|
  x.grand_total_points = x.total_points 
  x.save!
end
```

This takes me ages, because I have to update a million record. 
Total_points have already been defined in my user model where it calculates all the users points that have been submitted. Forgive me for my explanation. Is there a way to use update_all method but with each included in it?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, possible:

```
User.update_all('grand_total_points = total_points')
```

It will generate the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE "users" SET "grand_total_points" = 'total_points'
```

If `total_points` is not a column but an instance method, move the logic into `update_all` query.

```
User.update_all("grand_total_points = #{total_points calculation translated into SQL terms}")
```

Comment: `total_points` is different for each user, you only can use this if `total_points` is same for all users.

Comment: @ThanhHuynh it was a typo, there should have been a colon before `total_points` (`:total_points`)

Comment: I tried, it does not work. This code will update `grand_total_points` column of all users to `total_points` string.

Comment: it raised error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_points" does not exist`, `total_points` is a method in User model, so I wonder how it can be referenced when using `update_all`.

Comment: @ThanhHuynh I do not really understand who are you :) I mean, are you OP under different account? Anyway, if `total_points` is not a column, than show me how you implemented the `total_points` method - it should be then moved into the `update_all` query

Comment: No, I am not OP, but I want to try your code because I don't know this before and curious to know if it works :)

Comment: @ThanhHuynh I see, ok :) Right, if it's a method, as I said move the logic into `update_all` query. So `User.update_all("grand_total_points = #{total_points calculation translated into SQL terms}")`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Hi, yup total points column is not in the database. I think i used this to find the total points of current user. I used this to define the total points in my User model. 
 
def total_points
    self.points.sum(:value)
 end

Comment: @EjayTan do you expect me to react to this comment somehow? :) I edited the answer, can't help any further without more details

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'm not sure. I'm looking to take any creative solution to solve the problem. But thanks you for your response nevertheless.

Comment: Ex: I have `User` model and `message` column, and `random_text` method with this code: `SecureRandom.hex`. So I wonder how do I update `message` column of all users using `random_text` method, incase `random_text` is complex method.

Comment: @EjayTan I have provided you ***with the solution***. Just put the `total_points` logic into the `update_all` query.

Comment: @ThanhHuynh Let's take it another way around. you have a model `User`. It has two columns: `name`, `email`. You want to update all `name`'s to be equal to `email` column. it is possible with `User.update_all('name = email')`. It will set each users name dynamically to its email yet in single query. What you provided as an example is nitpicking (which is always good). You should always use the right tool. If `update_all` is a good choice - use it.

Comment: Ok, it seems we can not use method with `update_all` if that method can not be translated to SQL [update all with method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231610/update-all-with-a-method)

Comment: @ThanhHuynh correct, this is what I pointed out in the beginning of our discussion: `total_points calculation translated into SQL terms`

Answer (score 0):

I found something that could work. So basically i combine a ruby code with an execute SQL statement, and I put it in a migration file. Here's how the code works. I hope this helps. Make sure you follow the query according to your data.

```
class ChangeStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    points = Point.select('user_id, SUM(value) AS value').group(:user_id)
    points.each do |point|
    execute "UPDATE users SET grand_total_points = #{point.value} WHERE users.id = #{point.user_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

You should run bundle exec rake db:migrate after that. The normal way takes me 2-3hours. This only took me 2minutes.