# Rails 5 bulk-update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I need to do is something like this:

```
users.update_all(number: some_specific_number_different_for_each_user)
```

Is there a better way of doing it other than iterating through users and updating each one separately? Even if I enclose it in transaction, it seems very inefficient...

Or is there a way to just save all records once I adjust the value, something like:

```
users.each_with_index { |u,i| u.number = i }
users.save_all
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use raw SQL, but doing it will skip any callback or validation.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless the value to be updated can be set by the SQL function.

See(EDIT2)
[update_all with a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231610/update-all-with-a-method)